# Remove duplicate elements from array list based on matched fields with different objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to remove duplicate elements from arraylist based on matched fields from two objects.I have two lists

```
    List<SalesNotify> notifies=salesNotifyService.getAllNotify();
```

Here i am getting all the notifies from the database.Second list is

```
    List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
    events= salesNotifyService.getEventsFromGoogleCalendar();
```

Here I am getting all the events from google calendar api.

Here one thing to note is after getting Events from google i am iterating over events object and setting it to SalesNotify like this

```
    for (Event event : events) {  /* events obtained from second list.Here i am setting every event obtained from google to SalesNotify object fields */
                SalesNotify salesNotify = new SalesNotify();
                salesNotify.setEmployeeName(event.getSummary());
                String date = event.getStart().getDateTime().toString();
                String dateEnd = event.getEnd().getDateTime().toString();
                salesNotify.setNotifyDate(date);
                salesNotify.setNotifyEndDate(dateEnd);
                salesNotify.setNotifyType("other");
                salesNotify.setDumId(event.getId());
                allNotifies.add(salesNotify);
              }
```

I have third list where i am adding these two lists and sending it.Here is third list

```
    List<SalesNotify> allNotifies = new ArrayList<SalesNotify>();
```

I am adding the list of SalesNotify obtained from database like this

```
    for(SalesNotify notify : notifies){ /* notifies obtained from first list */
            allNotifies.add(notify);
        }
```

Now what i am trying to do is i am iterating over SalesNotify list and Event list and comparing for one field from SalesNotify and one field from Event list like this

```
    for(SalesNotify notify : notifies) {
      for(Event event : events) {
        if (notify.getShortNote().equals(event.getSummary())) { /*for example both have data "testing" */
            allNotifies.remove(event);
        }
      }
    }
```

I am adding notifies and events list to allNotifies and returning it to frontend for displaying.But here allNotifies.remove(event) is not working.I am able to enter if loop but it is not removing the event from the list.I want to remove event from allNotifies list if it satisfies the condition.I want to keep SalesNotify object data.Now it is displaying twice.Can anyone tell how to do this?

Comment: How could you remove an Event from a List of SalesNotify? That's like trying to remove all eggs from a basket of apples: that won't remove anything, because an egg is not an apple. It's also unclear how you populate allNotifies, and why you want to remove elements afterwards, instead of not adding them in the first place.

Comment: but allNotifies contains list of events also

Comment: So Event extends SalesNotify? How about posting a complete, minimal example reproducing the issue, instead of forcing us to guess?

Comment: Nope.After getting events from google i am setting those Event field values to SalesNotify object

Comment: Could you show us the code where you add the Event objects to the `allNotifies` list?

Comment: I have posted in my question.After setting values i am adding it to allNotifies list

Comment: So your list doesn't contain events. That's a bit like saying that a basket of cakes contains eggs, because you used eggs to make the cakes. You can't remove eggs from a basket of cakes, even if the cakes were made with eggs.

Comment: Ohh ok I know theres something wrong happening.

Comment: I am adding salesNotify object to allNotifies after setting each Event object from the list.Here if i add events list to allNotifies it throws error while add

Answer (score 0):

If you are iterating over a List using for loop, It locks the array during the iterations and it does not allow any modifications to the array while it is being used. So you cannot remove the element, if you are using the for loop. It throws ConcurrentModificationException if you are trying to remove the element from list.

Instead, Use Iterator to remove the elements from the list when iterating over the list. It allows you to remove the elements without any error.

Comment: That's true (sort of), but it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: What you are saying is correct. However it doesn't apply in this case, since he is not iterating over the list he is trying to modify.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a List of one type, but would like to remove the elements based on some common attributes from another class? If so, have you considered using a Map? Use the attributes you would like to use as a key (I would suggest a [MultiKey](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/keyvalue/MultiKey.html) if you have more than one attribute) then just remove by that key? If you can have more than one element with the same key, then you might also want to use a [MultiValuedMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html).